# How to get a single char from a pointer to a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm working with a method that must take a pointer to a pointer. I was wondering how I would go about getting the individual char values in this variable? For example:

```
void spacer(char **ptr) {

    int i;
    for(i = 0; **ptr[i] != ' '; i++) {

        printf("Is not space");

    }
}
```

I'm unsure how to accomplish this without getting a compilation error or segmentation fault.

Comment: What does the `char** ptr` value represent semantically? Is it a pointer-to-a-string or is it an array-of-strings?

Comment: That method doesn't have to take a pointer-to-pointer, btw. There is no modification to `*ptr`. Given only what we see, `char const *` and appropriate caller invocation should be sufficient.

Comment: @dai: "*or is it an array-of-strings*" how can a `wtf*`-typed variable ever be something else then just a pointer?

Comment: @alk When arrays decay to pointers. A `char* array[]` declaration (which represents an array of `char*` strings) decays to `char**` when passed into a non-template function.

Comment: Give as a function's parameter a `char * a[]` is equivalent to `char ** a` and defines `a` to be nothing more or less than pointer to pointer to `char`. @Dai

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ptr` points valid memory and `*ptr` does as well then`(*ptr)[i]` gets you a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

If ptr is just a double layer pointer, you can move it to make a local variable to make it simpler.

`char* str = *ptr;`

Then access it like a normal string later on.

`str[i] == ' '`

Also be careful about not leaving the allocated buffer. You need to either know the length or watch out for a null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

ptr is a pointer to pointer to `char`,so de-referencing it once will target a pointer.de-referencing it twice will target a `char`.

So `**ptr` will get you the first character.to loop over the characters you may use the following notation:

`*(*ptr + i)` which is equivalent to `(*ptr)[i]`

Answer (score -1):

you may try this:

```
char *temp=NULL;
int i;
temp=(char *)malloc(strlen(*ptr));
memset(temp,'\0',strlen(*ptr)+1);

for(i=0;i<strlen(*ptr)+1;i++)
{
    if(temp[i] != 32)
       printf("not space!\n"); 
}
```